# Unable to get the output from node.js program?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Here is my first file named `serverpaths.js`

```
var http = require("http");
var url = require("url");
function start() {
function onRequest(request, response) {
var pathname = url.parse(request.url).pathname;
console.log("Request for " + pathname + " received.");
response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});
response.write("Hello World");
response.end();
}
http.createServer(onRequest).listen(8888);
console.log("Server has started.");
}
exports.start = start;
```

Here is my second file named `router.js`

```
function route(pathname) {
console.log("About to route a request for " + pathname);
}
exports.route = route;
```

Here is my third file named `index1.js`

```
var server = require("./serverpaths");
var router = require("./router");
server.start(router.route);
```

The output should be

```
Server has started
Request for /foo received. 
About to route a request for /foo
```

But I am getting the output

```
Server has started
Request for /foo received
```

**I don't know why I am not getting the output from router** i.e. `About to route a request for /foo.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need call the function that you are passing through to your start function at some point.

```
var http = require("http");
var url = require("url");

function start(route) {
  function onRequest(request, response) {
    var pathname = url.parse(request.url).pathname;
    console.log("Request for " + pathname + " received.");
    route(pathname);
    response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});
    response.write("Hello World");
    response.end();
  }
  http.createServer(onRequest).listen(8888);
  console.log("Server has started.");
}

exports.start = start;
```

Comment: Thanks man it worked.actually i am a newbie in node.js so just one last question after `server.start(router.route);` how the flow will work firstly it will call `start` or `route` method.Could you plz explain the flow in brief.I understand what each and every line is doing but unable to understand actual flow.

Comment: The line `server.start(router.route)` will not call the router.route function. It will just pass it to the server.start function as an argument. You can then call the function in server.start.

Comment: In this simple case you could also do `var router = require('./router');` in serverpaths.js and then call `router.route(pathname)` when you need to.

Comment: So route function will be passed to the start function as callback function.Then start function firstly exceutes and the we get get output `About to route a request for /foo` from this line `route(pathname);`.Is this right?

Comment: The most funny thing I found about node js is that if we pass a function as an argument to another function.We get the output directly from the function passed in the argument.In java if a function returns a list  then firstly we have to store it in a list variable and then print it using System.out.println.But here we are directly getting the output from just the function which is passed as a parameter.Funny isn't it.BTW Thanks